# Get button id of a form in cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've two forms on the same page. On clicking any one of the buttons, both queries of the buttons are being submitted as I've used the function `IsPost` like `if(IsPost){ //run queries}`

Since both the forms are on the same page, on submission of any button, both the events of the two buttons are triggered.

I want to run separate queries on submission of each of the buttons.

In php, we used `if(isset($_REQUEST['buttonname'])){ //run queries }`.

Is there any such way, I can achieve the same in cshtml?

**Update**

What if I already have passed a value in the buttons?

Like for eg:

`<div class="btn-group pull-right">
           @{
           var followersearchcommand = "SELECT * from follow where follow_followerid = @0 and follow_followingid = @1";
           var followsearch = db.Query(followersearchcommand, follower_id, row.student_id);
           }
           @if(followsearch.Count > 0){
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="unfollow_followingid" value="@row.student_id" title="Follow" style="display: none"></button>
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="unfollow_button" value="unfollow" title="Follow">UnFollow</button>
           }
           else{
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="followingid" value="@row.student_id" title="Follow" style="display: none"></button>
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="follow_button" value="follow" title="Follow">Follow</button>
           }
      </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign to both buttons the same name and test their value:

```
@{
    if (IsPost){
        if(Request["button"] == "buttonA"){
            // button A is pressed
        } else {
            // button B is pressed
        }
    }
}

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="buttonA" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="buttonB" />
</form>
```

**Edited**

If you want to have two distinct forms, you could use the IsEmpty() method:

```
@{
    if (IsPost){
        if(!Request["buttonA"].IsEmpty()){
            // button A is pressed
        } else {
            // button B is pressed
        }
    }
}

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonA" value="buttonA" />
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonB" value="buttonB" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form id="a">
    <button type="submit">Submit A</button>
</form>

<form id="b">
    <button type="submit">Submit B</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Query A
        alert('A');
    });

    $("#b").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Query B
        alert('B');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/zZKE3/)

Edit:

You can make an ajax call to your controller's action:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")",
    data: { /* your data */ },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // success
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // error
    }
});
```

And in your controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult actionName(/* your data */)
{
  var success = DoSomething();

  if (!success)
  {
    throw new HttpException(500, "Server error!");
  }

  return Json("");
}
```

Something along those lines...

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I do this cshtml? I knew the Javascript. But how can I run the query? Where do I put the code of the query?